# SED: unterminated `s' command at hyphen

Tags: sed, provisioning

I'm running the following in my provisioner

```
sed -i 's/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/app\/web-root\/\g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

however I'm getting the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unterminated 's' command` - which is a hyphen (-) at that position. I've tried escaping it (`\-`) to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line:

```
sed -i 's/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/app\/web-root\/\g ...
                                                                          ^
```

sed needs `s/.../.../g` you have escaped the last `/` before `g` flag, more than that, you escaped `g` flag too. At least this mistake won't let your sed command go.

what better is, you pick another delimiter, if your pattern/replacement containing `/(slash)` too. It can save those dozens back slashes:

```
sed -i 's#foo/bar/blah#foo1/bar1/blah1#g` file
```